# How to view designated Ubuntu file partition after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, filemanager

I was finally able to get Ubuntu 15.04 to fully install and boot on my laptop. Then found that when I opened the file manager, there was only one of my two partitions (I have one for windows and one for Ubuntu) showing up on the sidebar, it is labeled "169 GB Volume". When I click it, it shows my windows files.

But, back when I was in the "Try Ubuntu" mode, it showed these windows files AND the Ubuntu files (like bin, boot, lib, etc.) under labels "169 GB Volume" and "139 GB Volume".

How do I get the Ubuntu-based file  to appear in the sidebar (either alone or alongside the windows volume)?

Comment: Ok so I rebooted for about the 50th time in the last few days and the folder "Computer" shows up and now I can see all my Ubuntu files. Of course it's after I ask the question that the problem solves itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu partitions are mount at start. That's why they are not shown as separate "disks" in file manager.

You can see all these system files and directories if you click on "Computer" in your file manager.

In most cases you do not need to do anything with system files.

All your files are in your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

As far as viewing Ubuntu's root ( / ) directory (same as Windows' C:\ folder) , Pilot6 has already gave you the correct solution: click on the "Computer" icon in file manager's left panel. Alternatively use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> shortcut, which opens address bar, type in / , and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. File manager will jump right to the root directory.

Now , as far as listing all existing partitions goes, Terminal (aka command line, same as cmd on Windows ) will be the way to go. You can use `sudo parted -l` , `lsblk` , `sudo blkid`, `sudo fdisk -l`, or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`. IMHO, if your task is to list partitions, terminal is the best approach